# inputing code on ssrs reports

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to know if is possible to use c# code on SSRS reports ? By code, I mean using events, functions and other things to make my report. The scenario working is on Visual Studio 2012. Thx for all.

Comment: Did you try it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. One way to do this is to deploy your c# code onto the sql server as a CLR, and expose it as a stored procedure. Then from the report stored procedure you could call the C# CLR stored procedure to get results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Microsoft doesn't make it very clear when comes to using c# on ssrs. Can you show me the process, like: Create code on c#, then make it an assembly, then add the assembly to the report. I just cant see that happening. When reporting comes to my mind, i see access 2000 easy use of code and reporting... Its like the report was a windows form, can i work like that in ssrs ?

Comment: I wanna thx Petio for helping, I found out another article that can help too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx